# SMSGlobal POST URL format sent by SMSglobal to receive 1 image attached MMS to your server.

Tags: php, mms

I am implementing a Receiving MMS application in php. I am using SMSGlobal gateway to receive MMS. As per their API documentation they have enlisted the parameters they send with the POST URL.

I want to know exactly what will SMSglobal send when there is only 1 image attached everytime in the MMS sent by the sender to me.

[The parameter enlisted by smsglobal can be checked here.](https://www.smsglobal.com/apis/mms-api/#Incoming_MMS) I have used same parameter names but I want to know what will be the value of the "attachmentx" when there is only 1 image attached in MMS, where x is the integer value.

Please tell me the parameters name and the values in the URL. Let me know the Format of the URL. 
Thank You